# How can I override a class with css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have `<div id="SearchBox" name="Control" class="ms-floatLeft">`. The class forces a SearchBox box to be left aligned within the div.

Is there a way to center align the SearchBox by overriding the class? The reason is I cannot edit the HTML directly but via a referenced style sheet I could potentially change the alignment.

I tried:

```
div#SearchBox {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

without success. Also !important doesn't help, the class always seems to take precedence.

What can I do here?

Comment: A class selector has less specificity than an id selector. So your issue must be somewhere else. Do you have any JavaScript which adds styles?

Comment: We can only make (more or less) educated guesses on the nature of your issue unless you show us the error. Just describing the error won't help. Please provide a  [mcve]

Comment: <style>Your css</style>

Comment: That's a good point that liran has here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since the applied class is called `ms-floatLeft`, the element has a `float: left;` style.
Add `float: none;` to your `#SearchBox`

```
#SearchBox {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and make your edits on the `ms-floatLeft` class since that's where the original styles are coming from.

If that class also has margin styles they will take precedence over the margin change you try and make on your end. BUT, if you use !important your styles will overwrite the original styles.

```
.ms-floatLeft {
    width: 50% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

It's worth noting that !important isn't always recommended but if this is 3rd party CSS and you don't have access to the original CSS file you may have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

The class `ms-floatLeft` seems to indicate that the element is left floated (in fact I just confirmed by looking at SharePoint stock CSS). Cancel this property in your override:

```
#SearchBox {
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try making it important as follows, it might not be the best solution

```
div#SearchBox {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
align:center!important;
```

}